# Eos-sharp jungle Error 3090003 when trying to call external smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, inline-action, c#

I’m trying to achieve something quite simple.
I try to call eosio.token transfer from one of my smartContract (lomtaxjungle dopurchase), but after severals days i still don’t manage to do it.
From what i understand this is a permission issue, so i added the lomtaxjungle@eosio.code to lomtaxjungle active public key.
But still when i try to transfer EOS from one account to another with the dopurchase action it returns :

```
Error 3090003:
unsatisfied_authorization
Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
```

So I think there is still something I don’t understand but I can’t figuring out what!

Here is my smart contract code :

```
ACTION purchase::dopurchase(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo) 
{
    require_auth(from);

    action
    {
        permission_level{from, "active"_n},
            "eosio.token"_n,
            "transfer"_n,
        std::make_tuple(from, to, quantity, memo)
    }.send();
}

EOSIO_DISPATCH(purchase, (dopurchase))
```

My lomtaxjungle permissions:
https://jungle.bloks.io/account/lomtaxjungle#keys

And my c# call to my contract:

```
    string result = "";

        result = await esoManager.CreateTransaction(new Transaction()
        {
            actions = new List<EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action>()
            {
                new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                {
                    account = "lomtaxjungle",
                    authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                    {
                        new PermissionLevel() {actor = accountLoged.AccountName, permission = accountLoged.Authority },
                    },
                    name = "dopurchase",
                    data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "from", accountLoged.AccountName },
                        { "to", to },
                        { "quantity", "0.0001 EOS" },
                        { "memo", "you transefered 0.0001 EOS to " + to }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your inline action, you are trying to transfer the funds onto the `to` account, but you are trying to do this with the permission of the from account, but it should be with the permission of `self`.

So change your inline action to say:

```
action
{
    permission_level{get_self(), "active"_n},
        "eosio.token"_n,
        "transfer"_n,
    std::make_tuple(get_self(), to, quantity, memo)
}.send();
```